# Insert date using c# in MS Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Can anyone tell me what wrong i am doing while inserting date in into ms access?
I am inserting date using below sql statement and date format is `d-M-yyyy`

```sql
insert into tbl_date(date_value) values(#8/7/2014#)
```

It's not showing me any error but store in access `7-Aug-2014` instead of `8-Jul-2014`

what is solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is that date format defined? In C# or Access?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty i have fired this sql statement in c#

Comment: Do you have to insert a fixed date or this is just a test code? Because the correct approach is to use a parameterized query where dates are correctly handled by the db engine without resorting to a formatting rules

Comment: @Steve Actually i have date in this format. now i want to insert it in access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In database  date format is MM/DD/YYYY
it's insert 8 as month and 7 as day

please check it as

```
insert into tbl_date(date_value) values(#7/8/2014#)
```

Comment: i got it i have converted it from d-M-yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy..and than inserted thanx. it worked

Answer (score 1):

Access, whether you like it or not the Date format is Month-Date-Year. Not the "normal" Date-Month-Year. So you are in need of a Format function that will parse the normal date to the format of MM/DD/YYYY. I am not sure what C# functions are, but in VBA one would use the Format function like.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_date(date_value) VALUES (Format(Date(), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"))
```